# jqGrid cell as minutes/seconds and incrementing

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

couldn't find any example for what I have so maybe you can help me out.

I have a grid that's querying the update time of a sql table. The result comes as an `int` from a `DATEDIFF`. And what I want to achieve in the jqgrid cell is: Showing the amount of minutes/seconds (let's say the int I have) since the table's been updated, and let it increment as seconds go by.

For instance, as soon as the grid refreshes that particular cell would be 8. And what I'd like to happen is for it to keep increasing as seconds pass by. After 20 seconds I'd like it to be 28 and so on.
The desired final result would include some cast and concatenation so I can show 25:12+.

Do you know of any way I can edit a jqgrid cell like that?
Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

DB Table.

```
Name              Update

UsersTable        SomedatetimeValue
AddressesTable    SomedatetimeValue
```

and so on

The jqGrid I'd like to show would be something like

```
UsersTable      8:10    
AddressesTable  6:35
```

being those 8:10 and 6:35 the values that I want to increment as seconds pass by. So, the user when he sees the grid knows how long since the last update on those particular tables.

Comment: So you want one cell in your jqGrid to start with the time since a table was last updated and then increment every second.  To clarify, you only want this as one cell in a column that is going to be updated? or would it be better to have this as an external item, as possibly a label or such as part of the header? It seems a waste to me to have a whole column that would then only be relevant for one cell that would be pertinent to your feature.

Comment: It's the entire column that'll have the same specs. Seconds/minutes increasing as time passes by. The grid has 2 columns. 'Name' and 'Last update happened...' So this 2nd column should have the increasing time.

Comment: And you want every cell in that column to have the same initial value, and then all be updated to show the increasing time?

Comment: I've added some info to my question, Think it's needed to explain myself clearly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I would do it:

Pass the value down from your controller as you describe.

Add a class to the column showing the time via:

```
classes: 'LastUpdateTimeClass'
```

On the load of the jqGrid setup a timer function to update each of those values that have the class. Ex (inside of jqGrid setup)

```
loadComplete: function () {
    if (timer) {window.clearinterval(timer)}; //clear the timer

    //setup the timer
    self.setInterval(function () {
      $('.LastUpdateTimeClass').each(function () {                              
          $(this).text(parseInt($(this).text(), 10) + 1); 
      });
    }, 1000);
}//loadComplete
```

Comment: Thanks Mark. Do you know of any other timer function? I'm trying with setInterval(function(){ /*code*/ }, 1000); but I can't make it work.

Comment: I edited the post, I think it should be a fairly straightforward timer function call.

Comment: The problem I commented was I'm calling the grid from .ajax, so I have to use gridComplete instead of loadComplete. Anyways, it's not working. After grid is filled, the value of minutes/seconds shows and after the first second, it refreshes to 1. After that it just stops refreshing. It doesn't add 1, it replaces it with 1 and then stops.

Comment: I updated the code, but I have tested it and the function is incrementing the values in the columns having the class every second. You can always test the `self.setInterval` from a Firebug window.